# how to migrate old version of Andriod embedding to v2 embedding

Tags: android, flutter

I'm building a quiz app using flutter and I need to download [rflutter alert package](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert/changelog), but the package is not downloading as it says the app is a deprecated version of the Andriod Embedding.

I have tried to solve the issue by following many StackOverflow answers to this very same problem, but none was able to help me resolve the issue so far.

Here is the pictures of the problem : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIDAL.jpg).

Somehow the **AndriodManifest.xml** file gives me 10 errors and when I try to fix them by following some stackoverflow answers, it just increases the amount of errors.

Can someone please help me to fix it?

Comment: Why dont you just follow this instructions: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
I had the same problem and after following the steps in the above url, my app was built perfectly

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow the instructions on the link, but the AndriodManifest.xml keeps showing errors. How do I fix that?

Comment: Does your app builds when you run it? If you app builds just ignore the android manifest errors.

Comment: yes, my app runs just fine, but I'm trying to download a package, and to do that I think I need to make changes to the AndriodManifest file. Should I go on and change the file even though it gives me errors?

Comment: Yes, can you make changes to your Manifest files. But the package you are trying to install rflutter alert package, in it's installation guide I am not seeing anything that says you need to change manifest to install the package